# C# How to turn off specific monitor?

Tags: c#, winapi

I know how to turn on/off all monitors by using user32.dll.

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) -1);
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM)  2);
```

But I want to turn on/off only single one.

Comment: You may need to use Windows' DDC/CI API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/monitor/using-the-low-level-monitor-configuration-functions

Comment: I cannot find a way of sending DDC/CI commands from C#...

Comment: You have found a way to declare and call `SendMessage` from C#; you declare these functions in the same way.

Comment: But I found only a way of sending DDC/CI API from C++, not C#. What kind of dll should I use?

Comment: The first result of putting `GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR library` into Google is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd692948(v=vs.71), which tells you it's Dxva2.dll.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to help me. I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dai is right. Use the [Low-Level Monitor Configuration Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/) can turn off a specified monitor.

The following is an example of selecting one monitor and turn off it, after 5 seconds turn it on.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")

const BYTE PowerMode = 0xD6;  // VCP Code defined in VESA Monitor Control Command Set (MCCS) standard
const DWORD PowerOn = 0x01;
const DWORD PowerOff = 0x04;

// Monitor description struct
struct MonitorDesc
{
    HANDLE hdl;
    DWORD power;
};

// Monitor enumeration callback
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    std::vector<MonitorDesc>* pMonitors = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<MonitorDesc>*>(dwData);

    DWORD nMonitorCount;
    if (GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &nMonitorCount))
    {
        PHYSICAL_MONITOR* pMons = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[nMonitorCount];

        if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, nMonitorCount, pMons))
        {
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < nMonitorCount; i++)
            {
                MonitorDesc desc;
                desc.hdl = pMons[i].hPhysicalMonitor;

                pMonitors->push_back(desc);
            }
        }
        delete[] pMons;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// Switch monitor power
void MonitorSwitch(MonitorDesc& monitor, DWORD mode)
{
    if (monitor.power == mode)
        return;

    SetVCPFeature(monitor.hdl, PowerMode, mode);
    monitor.power = mode;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MonitorDesc> monitors;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &MonitorEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitors));

    // Init
    for (auto& monitor : monitors)
    {
        monitor.power = PowerOn;
    }

    // Here select the first one monitor as example
    MonitorDesc targetMonitor = monitors[0];

    // turn off
    if (targetMonitor.power == PowerOn)
    {
        MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOff);
    }

    Sleep(5000);

    // turn on
    if (targetMonitor.power == PowerOff)
    {
        MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter! I think I can solve it thanks to you.

Comment: And now I have solved it! Thank you once again for everything you've done.

Comment: @GermMan Glad to help.

Comment: These don't seem to work on my Windows 10 v1909, neither off or standby, though Windows activates standby fine. Does it require Administrator rights? Also, shouldn't you do something / mention the need to call DestroyPhysicalMonitor(s)?

Comment: Other than being c++, for me this works only on my hdmi connected monitor, not the ones connected by displayport. Not sure if displayport is the culprit. Also, Microsoft does not support the command (0xD6), but it does work in some configurations.

Answer (score 2):

You could always run [ControlMyMonitor.exe](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html) from nirsoft.

As of version 1.20, you can turn monitors on and off using:

```
ControlMyMonitor.exe /SwitchValue "\\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0" D6 1 5
```