Is it possible to turn the display off knowing the monitor handle
I can control the monitor brightness using DeviceIoControl and handle to the display device:
handle = CreateFile(monitor, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

But I also want to turn that monitor off. Can it be done for the specific display?
I know the SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2); way.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066291/c-sharp-how-to-turn-off-specific-monitor

@HansPassant As I wrote I know this method, but you cant choose the display

It demonstrates SetVCPFeature().  For a specific display, that monitor handle you already have.  Did you try it?

@HansPassant it does not switch off my LCD (connected via eDP)
